# typeid doesn't return correct type

Tags: c++, typeid

```
cout << typeid(int&).name();
```

This, in my opinion, should return `int&` as a type, not an `int`, but on GCC 4.5.1 and on VS2010 SP1 beta it returns `int`. Why is this?

Comment: Better test: `cout << (typeid(int&) == typeid(int));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how typeid is supposed to work. When you apply `typeid` to a *type-id* of a reference type, the `type_info` object refers to the referenced type.

ISO/IEC 14882:2003, 5.2.8 / 4 [expr.typeid]:

> When `typeid` is applied to a *type-id*, the result refers to a `type_info` object representing the type of the *type-id*. If the type of the *type-id* is a reference type, the result of the `typeid` expression refers to a `type_info` object representing the referenced type. If the type of the *type-id* is a class type or a reference to a class type, the class shall be completely-defined. Types shall not be defined in the *type-id*.

Answer (score 6):

Your first mistake is expecting anything useful from `std::type_info::name()`. From the standard:

- §18.5.1/1: "*The names, encoding rule, and collating sequence for types are all **unspecified** and may differ between programs.*"
- §18.5.1/7: "*`const char* name() const;` Returns: an **implementation-defined** NTBS.*"

If you want a portable solution for meaningful (through not necessarily consistent) type names, I recommend using [Boost.TypeIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/type_index/)'s [`boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<>().pretty_name()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_typeindex/examples.html#boost_typeindex.examples.exact_type_matching_storing_type) ([reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/typeindex/type_id_with_cvr.html)).

Answer (score 5):

The C++ spec does not guarantee that `type_info::name` actually hands back the name of the type as it appears in the C++ source code; in fact, the spec, §18.5.1/7, only guarantees that the function hand back "an implementation-defined NTBS."

Consequently, there's no reason to assume that using `typeid` to get the name of a type will actually hand back the name of the type as you'd expect it to.

The reason you're seeing the type of `int` and not `int&` is that the definition of `typeid` says that it ignores references.  To quote the spec, §5.2.8/4:

> When typeid is applied to a type-id, the result refers to a type_info object representing the type of the type-id. **If the type of the type-id is a reference type, the result of the typeid expression refers to a type_info object representing the referenced type.**

(My emphasis)

This means that `typeid(int&)` and `typeid(int)` are completely identical to one another, hence the output being `int` and not `int&` or something related to it.