# std::is_arithmetic returns false for int type inside generic lambda: Undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, type-traits, boost-hana

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

#include <cxxabi.h>

#include <boost/hana.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

struct Person {
  BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Person,
    (std::string, name),
    (int, age)
  );
};

template<typename T>
void stringify(const T& v) {
    hana::for_each(hana::accessors<T>(), [&v](auto a) {
        // Here I'm printing the demangled type, just to make sure it is actually the type I'm thinking it is.
        std::cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(decltype(hana::second(a)(v)){}).name(), 0, 0, 0);

        // If the value is arithmetic, "quote" should be an empty string. Else, it should be an actual quote.
        // UNEXPECTED BEHAVIOR IS HERE
        std::string quote{(std::is_arithmetic<decltype(hana::second(a)(v))>::value?"":"\"")};

        // Finally do what we're here for.
        std::cout << " " << hana::first(a).c_str() << " = " << quote << hana::second(a)(v) << quote << "\n";
    });
}

int main() {
    Person john;
    john.name = "John Doe";
    john.age = 42;
    stringify(john);
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61efa6d9862a5388)

Output:

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string</*...*/> name = "John Doe"
int age = "42"
```

I'm trying to use `std::is_arithmetic` to tell if I'm dealing with a number instead of some other non-arithmetic type, and print (or not) a quote accordingly.

But for some reason, the value being "returned" (through `::value` member) is `false`, even though I'm passing an `int`(I make sure I'm doing that right by first printing the demangled type using gcc's `cxxabi.h`)

As you can see from the output, this causes the `int` to be printed with quotes.

My question(s) is: why is it returning false? Does this have anything to do with the generic lambda? Can I fix it?

*I'm actually testing this directly on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), so you can assume whatever gcc version used there (Currently 6.3.0).*

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d50720bf7bf64aa

Comment: @llonesmiz oohhh. I knew it had to be me being dumb somewhere. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: " printing the demangled type", one nice simple alternative is to add a variable declaration with invalid initialization, that produces the type description as part of the diagnostic. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that in spite of the [type `typeid` returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151875/typeid-doesnt-return-correct-type) (int) your actual type inside the lambda is `int const&` and `is_arithmetic` is not specialized for that exact type. [You can get the type you actually want with `std::decay` or a combination of `std::remove_const` and `std::remove_reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749557/get-base-type-of-a-template-type-remove-const-reference-etc).